# How much taxes should I be saving living in Chicago, IL?

Tags: united-states, taxes, form-1099

I work under the 1099 Taxes.  So I basically work as a contractor for a company in the Chicago IL area.  Currently I am setting aside 20% of my bi-weekly check and saving it to pay for taxes come January.

Is 20% enough?

Comment: Your total tax balance owed to the government will be based on many factors, especially your income. If you earn $5k, your tax balance will be $0. How much do you earn, when did you start working, what deductions will you be able to take, etc.

Comment: 30/hour but no deductions.  I know I can't deduct Lyft.  I wish.  I started working First week of June and until First week of January.

Comment: and how many hours a week will you be working?

Comment: 40 hours a week sir Bacon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is 20% enough?

As a self-employed 1099 contractor, you are required to pay your federal income and FICA taxes quarterly.  In order to calculate what you owe for your first quarterly payment, you will need to fill out [form 1040-ES](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1040es.pdf).  This will give you a good estimate of what your full year taxes will be, and how much you will need at each installment--better than guesstimates or rules of thumb from strangers on the internet.

Of course, you may have additional more targeted questions *after* working through the 1040-ES (or *while* working on it) that you could bring back here.

Similarly, Illinois has a [it's own 1040-ES](https://www2.illinois.gov/rev/forms/incometax/Documents/currentyear/individual/IL-1040-ES.pdf) with which you can estimate the state portion of your taxes.

Comment: According the site for me over 9,700 but not over 39,475 is  $970.00 = 12% total Federal taxes.  Plus the Illinois documents says 4.95%.  So total of 16.95%. I have been saving 20% but I am ready for 30% if need be.  I am just going to go to H&R Block just to be safe.  I don't want to mess this up.  

I just need to put in the information of the company that has been paying me for the contract?

Comment: @Treewallie I don't think you're including the self-employment FICA taxes from line 9 (and included worksheet) of the 1040-ES.

Comment: For Federal at least (and many states but I don't know IL) _if_ you didn't have any tax liability for the previous year, you don't actually need to make the estimated payments -- there's a safe harbor from the 2210 penalty and you can pay up til April 15. (You do need to have the money available then. And this is only the first year.) Note the 'quarters' are April June,Sept Jan, which are not truly quarters.

Comment: I looked at Line 9 for FICA Taxes and didn't see a number.  What are FICA taxes?

Comment: [FICA](https://www.ssa.gov/thirdparty/materials/pdfs/educators/What-is-FICA-Infographic-EN-05-10297.pdf) are the taxes to fund Social Security and Medicare.  Line 9 on page 8 of the 1040-ES is labelled "Self-employment tax", and requires you to first complete the worksheet on page 6.

Comment: Oh I see.  So FICA is 7.65% for 2019.  So 7.65% + 16.95% = 24.6% total due.  Thanks!

Comment: FICA is 7.65% _for W2 employees_.  For a 1099 contractor earning less than 130k, it should be about 14.2%, but *you need to complete form 1040-ES with your actual numbers to determine your estimated taxes*.

Comment: More to the point, as a self-employed person you're responsible for *both* sides of FICA. approximately 14.2% as @user4556274 suggested. A $50,000 AGI will require pay approximately $4370 FIT, $7100 FICA (that's both sides), and $2376 SIT, or about $13846 total. That's about **27.7%** effective. Remember, that's on a $50K AGI; it will get better/worse as you make less/more respectively; ex: a $40K AGI would be about 26.8% effective. a $100k AGI would be up to 34.5% effective. etc. Get an accountant that specializes in handling 1099 contractors. It's worth it.

Comment: @WhozCraig Makes sense.  I am willing to pay for someone to do the taxes for me.  I would have no idea how to do it.  And this is something I don't want to mess up and pay for later.  How much would I be looking to spend if I got a pro to do it for me?  And the AGI for me is around 37k.

Comment: With 37K AGI, your looking around $2810 FIT, $5254 FICA, and $1733 SIT. That's about $9797, or 26.4%. Prices for tax preparation vary wildly from firm to firm, so you'll have to do your regional homework. Props for looking ahead and not getting hit with penalties and/or an unexpected tax bill, btw.

Comment: @WhozCraig Looks like online everyone is saying 100-250 is a good price and people seem to complain about 350+ for 1099 tax services. I would have up-voted your help but I am still a newby on this stack.  I got lucky, I thought I had to file once a year after watching a 1099 video saying I could choose to do once a year or quarterly.  I was also told I would only need to save 10% for taxes.  I have been saving 20% but can make up for the extra I needed to save from now on.  Kudos to the help I have received.